# Cascade delete with optional records in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm

I'm trying to develop an ASP.net MVC application with Entity Framework and in last about 8 hours, i'm trying to fix something without a success. I have 3 models, `Overhour`, `Accounting` and `Vacation`. `Overhour` is the parent model, once we create an `Overhour`, we can create an `Accounting` or `Vacation` record with it for one time. We don't need to create one, so we can have an `Overhour` without an `Accounting` or `Vacation`. Important thing is, when we delete an `Overhour`, we should delete both `Accountings` and `Vacations` (if they exist).

I'm using code first, i tried it with Data Annotations but it seems when you can't do that with optional models so i'm using Fluent Api now. Here is the thing i'm using for relation between an `Overhour` and `Accounting`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Overhour>()
.HasOptional<Accounting>(s => s.Accounting)
.WithOptionalPrincipal()
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Even if i use CodeFirst, i use a plugin to create model diagrams for testing purposes and model looks fine too (i guess):

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2cSa.png) (it seems i can't include the image directly)

As i understand, it says "Cascade on End1Delete". So when i delete an `Overhour`, accounting record should gets deleted too, but it's not working, it just sets it to null.

Another thing is, i'm not sure which one is the parent. I mean, should i have an `Overhour` model like this:

```
class Overhour {
    ...
    public int AccountingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Accounting Accounting { get; set; }
}
```

Or something like this:

```
class Overhour {
    ...
    public virtual Accounting Accounting { get; set; }
}
```

Or maybe i should include this properties to Accounting model? Like this:

```
class Accounting {
    ...
    public virtual Overhour Overhour { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe i need to do both?

I'm so confused, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get cascade delete with optional records to work using this:

```
public class Overhour
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Accounting
{
    [ForeignKey("Overhour")]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Overhour Overhour { get; set; }
}

public class Vacation
{
    [ForeignKey("Overhour")]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Overhour Overhour { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Accounting>()
        .HasRequired(accounting => accounting.Overhour)
        .WithOptional()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Vacation>()
        .HasRequired(vacation => vacation.Overhour)
        .WithOptional()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Comment: Here is the thing, Accounting doesn't need to have an Overhour record. That's optional too. So when i try to use the code you gave, i get an error like `Cascading foreign key 'FK_dbo.Accountings_dbo.Overhours_AccountingId' cannot be created where the referencing column 'Accountings.AccountingId' is an identity column.`.

Comment: According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#CascadeDelete), if the foreign key field is nullable, then when the principal is deleted, the foreign key field of the dependent will be set to null; the dependent will not be deleted. I don't know how to make the foreign key field non-nullable and optional.

Comment: Yes, i think what i'm trying to do is impossible because both sides are optional. I will just use a custom code i guess. Thanks.